# How to add button to Nautilus toolbar in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, nautilus, button

How do I add bottons to Nautilus toolbar, such as delete, new folder, cut, paste, etc. 
In Ubuntu 11.04 I did that by editing the file "/usr/share/nautilus/ui/nautilus-navigation-window-ui.xml", but in 12.04 this file no longer exist.
So, how do I do that now?

Answer (score 0):

11.04 used Gnome 2, so it was a different Nautilus version at all.

To add *anything* to the UI you need to get the source code and, add what you want, of course this means getting to know GTK.